# Error!System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-4, schema

I am working on an E-commerce website but stuck on this error. Been stuck on this error took me hours to resolve this problem but cant help out.

**Entities:**

```
public partial class Cart
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public string ClientID { get; set; }
public int ProductID { get; set; }
public int Amount { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> DatePurchased { get; set; }
public bool IsInCart { get; set; }

public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
public Product()
{
    this.Carts = new HashSet<Cart>();
}

public int ID { get; set; }
public int TypeID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public double Price { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Image { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
public virtual ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProductType
{
public ProductType()
{
    this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
}

public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Model**

The entities and their mappings are correctly registered with Entity Framework.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Error**
Error I have been facing is shown below:

> Error!System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'GarageDBModel.FK_Cart_Product' was not loaded because the type 'GarageDBModel.Product' is not available. The following information may be useful in resolving the previous error: The required property 'Id' does not exist on the type 'Product'. at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.LoadAssemblyFromCache(Assembly assembly, Boolean loadReferencedAssemblies, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.ObjectItemCollection.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.ExplicitLoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, ObjectItemCollection collection, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action`1 logLoadMessage) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly assembly) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataOptimization.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) at ProductTypeModel.InsertProductType(ProductType productType) in c:\Users\Ch Umer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\Garage\App_Code\Models\ProductTypeModel.cs:line 16

Comment: Copy paste the error here instead of attaching the screenshot.

Comment: I have added the error .

Comment: map your relationships and primary keys explicitly using data annotation or fluent API. EF looks for properties named "Id" for primary keys after convention, your PK's are named "ID". Same for your FK's ProductID and TypeID.

Comment: You failed attaching the model image btw